# How to align the top of several columns of short equations?

Tags: tables, equations, align

I use `align` to generate a parameter group with a number at the center of the right side. Now I want to align the top of each column by adding `\vspace{0pt}`.
However, it doesn't work. Any other method to achieve this aim is appreciated! Any advice?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\vspace{0pt}
 \begin{aligned}
  a_1 &= \frac{x}{h},\\ a_2 &= \frac{h \rho v}{\mu},\\
  a_3 &= \frac{k}{2},
 \end{aligned}
 &&
 \begin{aligned}
  b_1 &= \frac{h}{h}, \\ b_2 &= \frac{h_0^2 \rho p}{\mu^2},\\
  b_3 &= \frac{h_0 j}{2}.
 \end{aligned}
 &&
 \begin{aligned}
  c_1 &= \frac{\mu t}{\rho h}, \\  c_2 &= \frac{h \rho \phi}{\mu^2},
 \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]

Comment: It would probably be best just to align each row.

Comment: @Ixy I suggest you to wirte your equations row per row using one `aligned` environment (`a_1 &= ... &\qquad b_1 &= ... &\qquad c_1 &= ... \\ ` and so on). I suggest you to add more space between your rows (for instance, you could use `\\[\jot]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
a_1 & = \frac{x}{h},
    &\qquad
b_1 & = \frac{h}{h},
    &\qquad
c_1 & = \frac{\mu t}{\rho h},        \\
%
a_2 & = \frac{h \rho v}{\mu},
    &\qquad
b_2 & = \frac{h_0^2 \rho p}{\mu^2}
    &
c_2 & = \frac{h \rho \phi}{\mu^2},   \\
%
a_3 & = \frac{k}{2},
    &
b_3 & = \frac{h_0 j}{2}.
    &&
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment to align the rows and columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" and "\extrarowheight" macros
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5ex}  % extra vertical space between rows
\begin{array}{ r @{{}={}} L @{\qquad} r @{{}={}} L @{\qquad} r @{{}={}} L }
  a_1 & \frac{x}{h}, & b_1 & \frac{h}{h}, & c_1 & \frac{\mu t}{\rho h}, \\
  a_2 & \frac{h \rho v}{\mu}, & b_2 & \frac{h_0^2 \rho p}{\mu^2} & c_2 & \frac{h \rho \phi}{\mu^2},\\
  a_3 & \frac{k}{2}, & b_3 & \frac{h_0 j}{2}. \\
\end{array} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I had thought of that one.  My version (not entered) used minipages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks. Actually, I just modified my answer to use an `array` environment, after I discovered a flaw in my original answer. Feel free to still post your `minipage`-based method!

Answer (score 1):

Since Micro replaced his `\phantom` (more or less) based answer, here is my `minipage` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\refstepcounter{equation}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
 \begin{align*}
  a_1 &= \frac{x}{h},\\ a_2 &= \frac{h \rho v}{\mu},\\
  a_3 &= \frac{k}{2},
 \end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
 \begin{align*}
  b_1 &= \frac{h}{h}, \\ b_2 &= \frac{h_0^2 \rho p}{\mu^2},\\
  b_3 &= \frac{h_0 j}{2}.
 \end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
 \begin{align*}
  c_1 &= \frac{\mu t}{\rho h}, \\  c_2 &= \frac{h \rho \phi}{\mu^2},
 \end{align*}
\end{minipage}\newline\vspace{\baselineskip}}\llap{(\theequation)}}
\end{document}
```

[image: column first]